# Using org.apache.commons.fileupload inside GenericPortlet.serveResource()

Tags: jsp, portlet, apache-commons-fileupload

I'd appreciate your insights on this!

I'm writing an application based on portlet2.0 and JSP. One of the JSPs includes a form which allows users to upload files. I'm using `dojo.io.iframe.send()` to upload the file, and address it to the url:*<* portlet:resourceURL/>, that is - to the `GenericPortlet.serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)` method.

As this is a multipart request, I can't access the input field parameter through `request.getParameter()`, and therefore using the `org.apache.commons.fileupload` package.
However, the `PortletFileUpload.parseRequest()` gets only an `ActionRequest` and not a `ResourceRequest`.

My work-around includes getting the `HttpServletRequest` object out of the `ResourceRequest`, and then using the `ServletFileUpload.parseRequest()`.

What do you think of this solution? Do you have any other suggestions for a proper work-around?

Thank you very much for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, answering to myself...

Coming to think of it, the `dojo.io.iframe` ***submits*** the form and doesn't really perform an AJAX call, so basically it is more correct to use the `_<_ portlet:actionURL/>` than the `_<_ portlet:resourceURL/>` - which naturally solves the whole issue.

Thanks anyway

Comment: On second thought, using _<_ portlet:actionURL/> refreshes the page, making the file upload look like a separate form, so I'm going back to _<_ portlet:resourceURL/> which doesn't cause any refresh.

Comment: Dude, you did it all by yourself!